# How to derive the Gibbs free energy for an ideal gas?

Tags: gas-laws, free-energy

> Determine the Gibbs Free Energy for an ideal gas and show that, this energy, and its derivative can be related to the enthalpy of the system via Gibbs-Helmholtz equation 
>   $$H = -T^2 \left( \frac{\partial (G/T)}{\partial T} \right)$$

So I need to determine the fundamental relation for an ideal gas in the Gibbs free energy representation.

**My thoughts:**

I know the Gibbs free energy, is defined by 
$$G(p,T) = U + pV - TS = H - TS,$$
where $H$ is the enthalpy, then
\begin{align}  
\mathrm{d}(U + pV - TS) &=
   V\mathrm{d}p - S\,\mathrm{d}T + \sum{\mu_i\,\mathrm{d}N_i}
   - \sum{X_i\,\mathrm{d}a_i}\\
\mathrm{d}G &=
   V\,\mathrm{d}p - S\,\mathrm{d}T + \sum{\mu_i\,\mathrm{d}N_i 
   - \sum{X_i\mathrm{d}a_i}}\\
\therefore \mathrm{d}G &= 
   V\,\mathrm{d}p - S\,\mathrm{d}T
\end{align}
Now, if the temperature is constant, and only the pressure change then $\mathrm{d}G = V\,\mathrm{d}p$. It follows that $$G(p)-G(p_0)=\int_{p_0}^{p}{V\,\mathrm{d}p}$$
If $V = \frac{nRT}{p}$, we have 
$$G(p) = G(p_0) + nRT \ln\left(\frac{p}{p_0}\right)$$

But, I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this question is asking for ? I don't know what the term "Gibbs Free Energy for an ideal gas" means. What the OP has derived here is the Gibbs Free Energy as a function of pressure, at constant temperature & mole number for an ideal gas. Initially my thoughts were, the OP desired the fundamental relation for an ideal gas in the gibbs free energy representation

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The Gibbs free energy is defined as: $G(p.T)=U+pV-TS$. So, I need find the expression $G(p,T)$ for a ideal gas. The other part of the problem is not difficult. Thanks

Comment: Okay. I think I get what you want, let me type out an answer for you :)

Comment: @getafix This is the first time I have studied these subjects, sorry for my mistake

Comment: I wrote a quick answer, to your post. Please edit your question to include the clarification you made in the comments. Ask me if something is unclear, I have to go now. I will fill in some steps later perhaps.

Comment: @MathUser Why the two sums are equal? Also why you need the second sum? $$dG=d(U+pV-TS)=-SdT + Vdp + \sum_{i} \mu_{i} n_i$$

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental relation for an Ideal Gas, in the entropy representation is

$$S(U,V,N) = 
   NS_0 + NR\ln\left[ \left( \frac{U}{U_0} \right)^c 
                      \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)
                      \left( \frac{N_0}{N} \right)^{c+1} \right]$$

The Gibbs Free Energy, is the Legendre Transform $G \equiv U[T,p]$

so, $G = U + pV -TS$

First, let's get the equation of state $S(T,V,N) $ from the the fundamental relation. We eliminate $U$ using $U = cNRT$

$$S(T,V,N) = 
  NS_0 + NR\ln\left[ \left( \frac{T}{T_0} \right)^c
                     \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)
                     \left( \frac{N_0}{N} \right) \right].$$

Also, for an Ideal Gas, $p =\frac{NRT}{V}$

$$G(T,p,N) = 
  cNRT - TNS_0 
  - NRT\ln\left[ \left( \frac{T}{T_0} \right)^c
                 \left( \frac{p_0}{p} \right)
                 \left( \frac{N_0}{N} \right) \right] + NRT $$

Exercise: Find $G_0 = G(T_0,p_0, N_0)$ and substitute into the fundamental relation derived above to get rid of $S_0$

Answer (score 6):

Yes you are partly on the right track.
 Your final equation is usually written in a more familiar form as 
$$G=G^{\ce{o} }+RT\ln\left(\frac{p}{p^{\ce{o}}}\right)$$ 
and letting $p^{\ce{o}}$ equal to $1$ atm then *p* is understood to be dimensionless and produces the free energy change with pressure
$$G=G^{\ce{o} }+RT\ln(p)$$ 
However, this does not help, and to get to your result you quote the basic equation you need which is 
$dG=Vdp-SdT$ 
and at constant pressure 
$$\left (\frac {\partial G}{dT} \right)_p =-S $$
(The eqn you need is at constant *p* although it is not indicated in the equation in your question). Next, as 
$$G=H-TS$$
 therefore 
$$G=H+T\left(\frac{\partial G}{dT}\right)_p$$

dividing through by $T^2$, working out the derivative $d(G/T)/dT$) and rearranging produces the Gibbs-Helmholtz equation.

Answer (score 2):

I think what they had in mind was for you to start with $$H(T,P)=H(T_0,P_0)+C_p(T-T_0)$$ and $$S(T,P)=S(T_0,P_0)+C_p\ln{\frac{T}{T_0}}-R\ln{\frac{P}{P_0}}$$So,$$G(T,P)=H(T_0,P_0)+C_p(T-T_0)-TS(T_0,P_0)-TC_p\ln{\frac{T}{T_0}}+TR\ln{\frac{P}{P_0}}$$